# How to deploy spring boot rest api and angular 6+ application with mysql in ubuntu 18 in digital ocean?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, version-control, ubuntu-18.04, angular-fullstack

I have created a web application using angular 6+ and spring boot. I use angular 6+ for front end and in my local machine angular project is run under http://localhost:4200. And I using spring boot maven project to create rest api for my application and it is run under http://localhost:8008/api. I use mysql as my database and database url is http://localhost/test_db.

Now I want to deploy this web application to vps. So all the users can access through static ipv4 address. (Ex: 123.46.79.1)

So I want to know how to deploy this web application correctly. And also specially I want to update the application time to time. So it is very important to have a easy method to update the full stack web application easily in future.

These are the 3 main components I want to deploy.

1. angular front end. (It should access from ipv4 address Ex. 123.45.67.8)
2. spring boot rest api.
3. Mysql Database. (It should access from navicate or some other tool remotely)

This is what I am currently knowing.
* connect digital ocean droplet using SSH key and Putty
* install ubuntu 18.2 on digital ocean
* install apache2

Please provide me the steps with the necessary ubuntu cli commands as well.

****note : I want to use only digital ocean for now.***

Thank you.

Comment: I've followed https://medium.com/@ldclakmal/deploy-a-java-web-application-in-digitalocean-882226dcdbd5 to host my backend in digitalocean

Comment: I haven't tried to host angular in digital ocean, but https://medium.com/@balramchavan/deploy-angular-application-in-nginx-server-on-digitalocean-ubuntu-droplet-28380524811e this might help you